# ARM resource iteration failing with an empty array

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-rm-template

It seems that all expressions in an ARM template are evaluated up-front, so even if you have condition `false` for a resource, expressions within that resource are evaluated.

This appears to be the case regardless of whether condition is explicitly set to `false` or if it's an expression that evaluates to `false`.

This behavior is problematic in the case resource iteration, because expressions within the resource may refer to the `copyIndex()` of a parameter or variable. However, that parameter of variable is an empty array, evaluation of those expressions will fail with a message similar to the following -

> The language expression property array index '0' is out of bounds.. Please see https://aka.ms/arm-template-expressions for usage details.

Is there any way I can amend my template to work regardless of whether or not there are any resources to add?

#### Example template

Note that I've already had to 'hack' the `count` parameter of the `copy` object. If it's `0` (as the expression `length(variables('productsJArray'))` may evaluation to), template validation fails with the following error -

> The copy count must be a postive integer value and cannot exceed '800'.

I feel that it's a reasonable expectation that if `count` is `0`, then no resource is added - but that's a whole different subject!

```
{
    "$schema": "http://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "parameters": {
        "apiManagementServiceName": {
            "type": "string",
            "metadata": {
                "description": "The name of the API Management instance."
            }
        },
        "productsJson": {
            "type": "string",
            "metadata": {
                "description": "A JSON representation of the Products to add."
            }
        }
    },
    "variables": {
        "productsJArray": "[json(parameters('productsJson'))]"
    },
    "resources": [
        {
            "condition": "[greater(length(variables('productsJArray')), 0)]",
            "type": "Microsoft.ApiManagement/service/products",
            "name": "[concat(parameters('apiManagementServiceName'), '/', variables('productsJArray')[copyIndex()].name)]",
            "apiVersion": "2018-06-01-preview",
            "properties": {
                "displayName": "[variables('productsJArray')[copyIndex()].displayName]",
                "description": "[variables('productsJArray')[copyIndex()].description]",
                "state": "[variables('productsJArray')[copyIndex()].state]",
                "subscriptionRequired": "[variables('productsJArray')[copyIndex()].subscriptionRequired]",
                "approvalRequired": "[variables('productsJArray')[copyIndex()].approvalRequired]"
            },
            "copy": {
                "name": "productscopy",
                "count": "[if(greater(length(variables('productsJArray')), 0), length(variables('productsJArray')), 1)]"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

#### Example parameters file that will work

Note that while this may seem fine, there may be instances in which the `productsJson` parameter value is any empty array, `[]`, and this is where my issue has arisen.

```
{
        "$schema": "http://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentParameters.json#",
        "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
        "parameters": {
                "apiManagementServiceName": {
                        "value": "my-api-management"
                },
                "productsJson": {
                        "value": "[{\"name\":\"my-product\",\"displayName\":\"My Product\",\"description\":\"My product is awesome.\",\"state\":\"published\",\"subscriptionRequired\":true,\"approvalRequired\":false}]"
                }
        }
}
```

#### Example parameters file that will fail

```
{
        "$schema": "http://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentParameters.json#",
        "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
        "parameters": {
                "apiManagementServiceName": {
                        "value": "lmk-bvt-conveyorbot"
                },
                "productsJson": {
                        "value": "[]"
                }
        }
}
```

## Updated template

Derived from one of the suggestions by user '4c74356b41'.

This template is generating the following error -

> Unable to process template language expressions for resource '/subscriptions/**********/resourceGroups/**********/providers/Microsoft.Resources/deployments/api-management-products' at line '1' and column '839'. 'The template function 'copyIndex' is not expected at this location. The function can only be used in a resource with copy specified.

```
{
        "$schema": "http://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
        "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
        "parameters": {
                "apiManagementServiceName": {
                        "type": "string",
                        "metadata": {
                                "description": "The name of the API Management instance."
                        }
                },
                "productsJson": {
                        "type": "string",
                        "metadata": {
                                "description": "A JSON representation of the Products to add."
                        }
                }
        },
        "variables": {
                "productsJArray": "[json(parameters('productsJson'))]"
        },
        "resources": [
                {
                        "condition": "[greater(length(variables('productsJArray')), 0)]",
                        "type": "Microsoft.Resources/deployments",
                        "name": "api-management-products",
                        "apiVersion": "2017-05-10",
                        "properties": {
                                "mode": "Incremental",
                                "template": {
                                        "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
                                        "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
                                        "resources": [
                                                {
                                                        "type": "Microsoft.ApiManagement/service/products",
                                                        "name": "[concat(parameters('apiManagementServiceName'), '/', variables('productsJArray')[copyIndex('productscopy')].name)]",
                                                        "apiVersion": "2018-06-01-preview",
                                                        "properties": {
                                                                "displayName": "[variables('productsJArray')[copyIndex('productscopy')].displayName]",
                                                                "description": "[variables('productsJArray')[copyIndex('productscopy')].description]",
                                                                "state": "[variables('productsJArray')[copyIndex('productscopy')].state]",
                                                                "subscriptionRequired": "[variables('productsJArray')[copyIndex('productscopy')].subscriptionRequired]",
                                                                "approvalRequired": "[variables('productsJArray')[copyIndex('productscopy')].approvalRequired]"
                                                        },
                                                        "copy": {
                                                                "name": "productscopy",
                                                                "count": "[if(greater(length(variables('productsJArray')), 0), length(variables('productsJArray')), 1)]"
                                                        }
                                                }
                                        ]
                                }
                        }
                }
        ]
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

two ways to work around this:

1. `if()` hack, so if `length == 0`, `length = 1`. Using this approach, you need to have a proxy object you will reference, as referencing a non existing object wont work.
2. Use nested deployments, you can put a condition on a deployment so it doesnt start if `length == 0` (and you run your loop inside the nested deployment). this way you dont care about length of zero.

Comment: Thanks for you're reply. I'm testing out number 2, but I'm getting an error that doesn't seem to make sense. I've added the updated template to the bottom of my question, and the error it's generating is `Unable to process template language expressions for resource '/subscriptions/**********/resourceGroups/**********/providers/Microsoft.Resources/deployments/api-management-products' at line '1' and column '839'. 'The template function 'copyIndex' is not expected at this location. The function can only be used in a resource with copy specified.`

Comment: yeah, it cannot be inline template. must be nested, unfortunately

Comment: Not sure what you mean? The example in my question is of a [nested template](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-linked-templates#link-or-nest-a-template). Or by nested deployment, do you mean nested resources?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-linked-templates#external-template-and-external-parameters

Comment: Oh, so you mean externally linked. That makes me sad, as it means I'll have to script a way of uploading my templates to a Storage Account, generate a SAS token from them, construct a URL and then pass that in to an additional template. Not sure it's worth pursuing :(

Comment: you can hack around without them, using first method

Comment: No need, turns out you can use `copyIndex()` in a [nested inline template](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/building-blocks/extending-templates/conditional-deploy). You just have to declare the 'copy' at the top level. The only downside is lots if individual deployments, rather than one single deployment. Hopefully this is something MS will improve in the future. I've added my working template as an answer for reference.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the final template that I will use. This allows me to pass either an array of objects or an empty array to the `productsJson` parameter.

```
{
    "$schema": "http://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "parameters": {
        "apiManagementServiceName": {
            "type": "string",
            "metadata": {
                "description": "The name of the API Management instance."
            }
        },
        "productsJson": {
            "type": "string",
            "metadata": {
                "description": "A JSON representation of the Products to add."
            }
        }
    },
    "variables": {
        "productsJArray": "[json(parameters('productsJson'))]"
    },
    "resources": [
        {
            "condition": "[greater(length(variables('productsJArray')), 0)]",
            "type": "Microsoft.Resources/deployments",
            "name": "[concat('api-management-products-', copyIndex())]",
            "apiVersion": "2017-05-10",
            "copy": {
                "name": "productscopy",
                "count": "[if(greater(length(variables('productsJArray')), 0), length(variables('productsJArray')), 1)]",
                "mode": "Serial"
            },
            "properties": {
                "mode": "Incremental",
                "template": {
                    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
                    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
                    "resources": [
                        {
                            "type": "Microsoft.ApiManagement/service/products",
                            "name": "[concat(parameters('apiManagementServiceName'), '/', variables('productsJArray')[copyIndex()].name)]",
                            "apiVersion": "2018-06-01-preview",
                            "properties": {
                                "displayName": "[variables('productsJArray')[copyIndex()].displayName]",
                                "description": "[variables('productsJArray')[copyIndex()].description]",
                                "state": "[variables('productsJArray')[copyIndex()].state]",
                                "subscriptionRequired": "[variables('productsJArray')[copyIndex()].subscriptionRequired]",
                                "approvalRequired": "[variables('productsJArray')[copyIndex()].approvalRequired]"
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also have a placeholder element in the empty array and use condition to ignore the placeholder element. like this

```
{
"parameters": {
    "yourArray": {
        "defaultValue": [
            {
                "name": "placeholder"
            }
        ],
        "type": "array"
    }
},
"resources": [
    {
        "condition": "[not(equals(parameters('yourArray')[copyIndex()].name,'placeholder'))]",
        "copy": {
            "name": "yourArray",
            "count": "[length(parameters('yourArray'))]"
        }
    }
]
}
```